# Can I do this with Magento?

Tags: magento2

I have never worked with magento before, just played around with a local installation of magento 2 for the last couple of days. I have technical background and can comfortably code in PHP if needed.

**Background**

I currently sell wholesale - all sales offline at the moment. All records are kept in Excel spreadsheets. I now want to start selling via following channels:

Wholesale
- online on my B2B website
- offline via phone orders etc (currently already do this, as above)
Retail
- online on a separate B2C website
- online marketplaces like ebay, amazon, facebook etc.

**The Problem**

I would like to sell via above channels whilst minimising admin work and centralising all data including product information, inventory information, orders, customer records etc.

**Proposed solution**

I think magento is my answer. The main reason for choosing magento is that it allows multi-site so I can run both B2B and B2C e-commerce websites from the same platform so half the battle is already won. But it's just as important to centralise data from other sales channels - with that in mind I can see it working as follows.

Data flow scenarios:

1. Magento will hold the product listings. The product listings will be PUSHED to market places e.g. ebay, amazon etc on adhoc bases.
2. Magento will PULL orders from market places periodically (once a day?). Magento will then use this data to:

   1. Create/update customer records held on Magento.
   2. Update product inventory records held on Magento and PUSH these back to market places.
   3. PUSH necessary information to courier systems for delivery label generation.
   4. PUSH financial data to external accounting system (might just be a massive CSV file for now).
3. Any online orders from the B2B ecommerce website and the B2C ecommerce website will automatically be created in Magento and manageable through the Magento admin panel.
4. Any offline B2B and B2C sales can be manually created in Magento through it's admin panel.

**Questions:**

1. What do you think of this solution for my requirements?
2. Have I missed anything important?
3. Is scenario no.1 and scenario no.2 above achievable with magento out of the box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In magento nothing is impossible. 
As per your background you need create three customer group

- Wholesale
- Retail
- Offline

When your site visitor/user register they will option for Wholesale/Retailer. These user use the frontend shopping cart for the shopping.

For the Offline user you can take order from the admin panel.

All the customers, products and orders will in single place. You can get report separately

Lastly, product & order PUSH and PULL, if they provide API it can also possible.

Comment: Hi Web Spider - thanks for responding. I don't want my wholesale and retail users to register from same website. If they are on wholesale website they should be registered as wholesale user automatically and if on retail website then they should be registered as retail user automatically. About PULL and PUSH, can you tell me a little bit how I can do it from magento? By the way I am using magento community version.

Comment: Use the magento REST API for the same